# how to save a file from browser to local directory by java script?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have to save a pdf file(which opens inside the browser) to the local directory on the same machine.

Any idea ,How to do it by java script or ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either politely inform the user of the *"right click » save as..."* functionality -  or serve the *PDF* with the following  *HTTP* headers:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=<FILENAME>.pdf
Content-type: application/octet-stream
```

Which implies that, <sup>[*(source: rfc2616)*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)</sup>

> *... the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.*

Beyond this you have no say in where a file should be saved for security reasons.

Comment: Actually the problem is,i have to create dynamically a folder with current logged in customer name in local drive and then pdf file should be saved inside that folder. I don't know how to create a folder in local drive by java script.

Comment: You can't - at least not by conventional means.  You might be able to do it with an ActiveX control given the right permissions on the client-side but you are then limiting your application to Microsoft / IE only... which probably isn't what you want if you tagged Sencha touch? Or maybe you could use a Java applet? If you are deploying a mobile application you'd likely be able to find a PhoneGap plugin (or write your own) but there's so many "ifs" and "buts" that the scope is too broad to answer - these are separate questions / solutions once you accurately determine what it is you are making.

Comment: PDF is generated from server side data,and displayed in a custom PDF view component in client browser(chrome).Inside this PDF view component we have two area: 1 (First part): contains email sending button and text field and close component button. 2:(second part): in this we have large text area to display pdf content.    Now we have a requirement to add a new Save As button in First part of PDF View component,in order to save this PDF to our local drive,in a particular customer(currently logged in).